# groovy.lang.missingMethodException when running code as a .jar

Tags: java, groovy, missingmethodexception, jsonslurper

I have this code in groovy to parse a json file:

```
File file = new File(configFile)
def config = new JsonSlurper().parse(file)
```

When I run it in Intellij it works just fine. I then build it to create a .jar then execute it in the terminal with: java -jar file.jar
I get the following exception executing it:

```
    Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.json.JsonSlurper.parse() is applicable for argument types: (File) values: [./resources/config.json]
Possible solutions: parse(java.io.Reader), use([Ljava.lang.Object;), wait(), any(), grep(), wait(long)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:70)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at org.forgerock.migrator.ConfigLoader.loadConfig(ConfigLoader.groovy:35)
    at org.forgerock.migrator.ConfigLoader$loadConfig.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at org.forgerock.migrator.processor.ProcessorFactory.getProcessor(ProcessorFactory.groovy:42)
    at org.forgerock.migrator.processor.ProcessorFactory$getProcessor.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at org.forgerock.migrator.Migration.main(Migration.groovy:35)
```

I've confirmed the groovy version to be 3.0.1. I have also tried running this on java 8 and 11. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

UPDATE:

Here is how I'm running the code with Groovy 3.0.1:

[image]

Comment: `parse` can take a `java.io.File`, but that doesn't seem to be the same as the `File` in your code.

Comment: older versions of groovy does not accept File for new JsonSlurper().parse(file). use: `new JsonSlurper().parse(file.newReader("UTF-8"))`. definitely your groovy runtime older then version 2.2

Comment: here is javadoc for verion 2.1: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.1.0/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure new JsonSlurper().parse(file.newReader("UTF-8")) will work. The question is why does it work in the IDE but it doesn't when executing the jar file when both Groovy versions are at 3.0.1? That's what puzzles me.

Comment: means that groovy version is different at runtime.

Comment: see my updated post with the Groovy version I'm running

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this problem. While troubleshooting the problem I decided to completely ignore the compilation warnings and the warning was telling me that it was a conflict of Groovy versions in the project.
This conflict came from a dependency I had in pom.xml. This specific dependency was adding Groovy 2.1.9 as a sub-dependency into the project so I had to remove it and the warning went away. Also JsonSlurper started working because now it was actually using version 3.0.1